# Link conda HDF4 to conda GDAL (Anaconda Python)

Tags: python, linux, centos, gdal, anaconda

I have python installed through the [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) distribution. It works for most regular things. I need to be able to open a MODIS HDF4-EOS file, however. I have tried

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/mutirri hdf4`

`conda install gdal`

`python -c "from osgeo import gdal; ds=gdal.Open("MOD021KM.A2014005.0910.006.2014005194151.hdf"); print type(ds)"`

But I get

> ERROR 4: `MOD021KM.A2014005.0910.006.2014005194151.hdf' not recognised as a supported file format.
>
> < type 'NoneType' >

hey... It seemed viable.

Does anyone know how to open an HDF4 file using Anaconda distribution of python 2.7 using GDAL?
I would greatly appreciate your help in doing so.

Thank you all.

Comment: By the way, I have gdal elsewhere on my system (without the python bindings) and can verify that using `gdalinfo MOD021KM.A2014005.0910.006.2014005194151.hdf` shows all the accurate information about the file. I cannot convince the sysadmin to reinstall gdal with `--with-python`... unfortunately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your question is not the same as this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110662/install-gdal-in-centos-without-root you should be able to use the method given in the accepted answer:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jgomezdans gdal=1.11.0
```

This version of GDAL from binstar is build with HDF4 support and will automatically install the conda HDF4 package. Best remove the existing GDAL and HDF4 packages you have already installed prior to getting the new ones.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Something important was to make sure my `${PATH}` environment is setup correctly. Otherwise, `conda` had some issues linking to previously installed HDF4, GEOS libraries.

Comment: Hi @jakebrinkmann, I am having the same problem as you. I tried the solution provided here but it seems the command "conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jgomezdans gdal=1.11.0" won't install hdf4 automatically.
I also tried the methods described here:
http://jgomezdans.github.io/new-version-of-gdal-packages-with-hdf-for-anaconda.html
However, it seems that the gdal is not linked properly with the hdf4 package when being compiled. 
I am sure my the anaconda installation path is perpended to my $PATH when I do the installation. Do you know what could be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: @wiswit Hmmmm, I just used the [instructions](http://jgomezdans.github.io/new-version-of-gdal-packages-with-hdf-for-anaconda.html) you linked to on CentOS 6.6, and it was successful at reading the HDF4 data.... What error do you see? Feel free to make a new SO question, and we can debug with potentially more help

Comment: @jakebrinkmann thanks for the answer! I am not quite knowledgeable in computer science (not knowing exactly all the processes involved in build, make ... etc). The error is simply that it complains the format (.hdf, MODIS data) is not supported. I do check that the hdf4 is not supported:
(Note that I am currently within the anaconda installation directory).
cyue@LGGE130:~/anaconda/bin$ ./gdalinfo --version
GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10
cyue@LGGE130:~/anaconda/bin$ ./gdalinfo --formats | grep HDF
  HDF5 (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
  HDF5Image (ro): HDF5 Dataset

Comment: @jakebrinkmann but it seems that I have hdf4 installed with anaconda?
cyue@LGGE130:~/anaconda/bin$ ./conda list hdf4
# packages in environment at /home/cyue/anaconda:
#
hdf4                      4.2.11                   py27_0

BTW, I am not using CentOS, I am using a Debian system.

Comment: @jakebrinkmann Further, I saw your post on the google group: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/ba1YzY5ENr8, I am having exactly the same situation as yours ...