# GDAL works in Bash but not Python

Tags: python, bash, macos, gdal, hdf

I have been fighting with getting GDAL installed properly for some time now, and just when I thought I had everything working properly I discovered another road block.

I have installed GDAL using the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346301/struggling-to-compile-gdal-with-hdf4-support), which is a form that supports HDF4 file formats.  For example, using `gdalinfo --formats` in bash returns a list of supported file formats, and HDF4 is included there.  In addition, `gdalinfo XYZ.hdf` returns a complete description of whatever hdf file I input.

However, when trying to work with HDF4 files through Python, I spring an error that HDF4 is not a supported file format.  Using

```
 import osgeo.gdal as gdal
 gdal.GetDriverByName('HDF4')
```

yields no return whatsoever.

I am confused because GDAL appears to be built properly for me, but I can't get it to work through Python.  I've explored [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333418/link-conda-hdf4-to-conda-gdal-anaconda-python) as well as [this source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110662/install-gdal-in-centos-without-root), but they describe GDAL installation with HDF4 support - which I've already accomplished.  For some reason it seems like Python doesn't know how to use the GDAL I've installed to its fullest potential...

Versions:
Mac OSX El Capitan Version 10.11.6; GDAL 2.2.1, released 2017/06/23

Comment: python probably comes with its own version of gdal libraries.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov ok, then what can I do to get python's gdal to support hdf4?

Comment: Is HDF4 in 

`for i in range(gdal.GetDriverCount()): 
    print i, gdal.GetDriver(i).GetDescription()`

Comment: @LoganByers no, it isn't.  Does that mean I need to install a driver, or rework gdal in python?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment or is there any chance you have multiple instances of GDAL installed on the computer?  For instance if you already had QGIS installed.

Comment: @LoganByers It's my own private computer.  I don't have QGIS installed, but I wiped my hard drive a few months back and tried over and over again to get gdal installed via bash using sudo pip install and homebrew...

Comment: @LoganByers It seems that I have a bunch of gdal libraries.  Accessing the installed python packages using `cd Users/myusername/anaconda/pkgs` I have both gdal-1.10.1-py27_1 and gdal-1.11.0-np19py27_0.  I'm going to try to remove one and see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, folks.  I'm not sure which exact steps I needed or were not necessary, so I'll post my full workflow in order to maintain transparency.

As per the comments of Dmitri and Logan above, I investigated as to whether or not I had the proper `gdal` *python* library, rather than simply a `gdal` bash library.  Still unsure of what the difference is, but as it turns out I had a couple different gdal libraries present within the packages subfolder in anaconda (`cd /Users/myusername/anaconda/pkgs`, `ls`).  I removed these libraries using `rm` and some tag (maybe `-r`?).

I then reinstalled my spatial libraries using anaconda, following the guidelines posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/135872).  Unfortunately my bash was unable to access the jgomezdans website but I was able to bypass this element of the equation by using `conda install proj4` (rather than `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jgomezdans proj4`), etc.

After installing all of the scipy stuff etc, I brought in `proj4`, `hdf4`, and `gdal` (in that order).  When trying to install `geos` I caught an error that it had already been installed.

With all of this completed, I used the command in my original post, as well as in Logan's comment, to check  that `HDF4` was present.  My command returns the following:

```
<osgeo.gdal.Driver; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDriverShadow *' at 0x10fc66180> >
```

Logan's returns a full list of the available `gdal` drivers in python's `gdal`.  Sure enough, `hdf4` is on the list.

**tl;dr** I uninstalled everything and reinstalled many things.